# How to add Ada to riscv-toolchain

Tags: ada, riscv, gprbuild

How to configure RISCV tool chain to support Ada ?
Does the gprBuild tool support the riscv64-unknown-elf toolchain? .....

I have tried using gprBuild tool by installing using the command:

```
sudo apt install gpr
```

After installation when searched for supported targets using the command

```
gprconfig --show-targets
```

it shows only 
x86-64-linux-gcc and there is nothing of RISCV tool chain

Comment: (Assuming you want to compile on x86-64 for a RISCV target)... You probably need to compile GCC as a cross-compiler, after configuring with --enable-languages=c,c++,ada. This is non-trivial and there are many ways it can go wrong.